# PDF Reader for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, pdf

I have just started with Linux Ubuntu 16.04 (Novice) Looking for PDF Reader for said OS.

Answer (score 2):

Foxit is a good and feature-rich PDF reader. Moreover Foxit is available for Windows too. You can connect the software to the cloud to sync your changes to a document accross multiple devices, be it Windows or Ununtu. I'd suggest going with it.

You can download it from the official website:

https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/

If you need help installing it, here's a guide that might help:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/09/install-foxit-reader-in-ubuntu/

Hope it helps.